# Tweeter API: How do I use Tweepy.cursor to search by key word (e.g. trump) and search by number of followers (e.g. greater than 10000)

Tags: tweepy

```
results = [] 
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="coronavirus",
                           result_type="recent",
                           include_entities=True,
                           wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                           wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True,
                           lang="en").items(50):
        results.append(tweet)
```

I know how to search keyword by using tweepy.cursor. But I want to append tweets only that a particular user has over 10000 followers and satisfy the keyword criterion. I am not sure how to do these two things simultaneously. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example Twitter Status JSON: https://pastebin.com/UB5XbrHe

```
"user":{
  ...
  "followers_count":46,
  ...
}
```

You can access the json in your case via `tweet._json`. Instead of

```
results.append(tweet)
```

you'll write:

```
if tweet._json["user"]["followers_count"] > 10000:
  results.append(tweet)
```